# I can't find the element //input[@type='file'] to upload changes to personal avatar information myaccount gg

Tags: file, upload

Now I want to change my avatar but I can't find the element //input[@type='file'] Can anyone help me with this problem?

[I can't find the element //input[@type='file']](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDnYj.png)

I can't find the element //input[@type='file'] in web....